# How can I force IE to keep applying opacity to an overlay while the element underneath is being animated?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, filter, opacity

I have a slideshow (using jQuery Cycle) which includes an overlay.  The overlay uses CSS opacity and filters.  jQuery is doing the same for the animation.

In IE 6/7/8, the filter used to give the overlay opacity fails while the animation is running and shows grey.

I think the problem is that IE can't use two filters at once.  Is there anyway around this?

All of the code is on JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/ucizox/6/edit

Comment: Why don't you just use a transparent png as the background image for the .trans divs?

Comment: Thank you, John.  I was so far down the path of using opacity, I didn't think about using a transparent image.

Comment: I'm still using opacity for modern browsers and targeting the transparent images at IE 6/7/8 using the star hack.

Comment: Yeah, personally I would just stick with the transparent image that repeats.  I do not know of a reason to use opacity unless you are fading the alpha on something.  To me this is just a duplication of effort and two places where you have to change when you want a different color/transparency.

Comment: I'm thinking in terms of page performance and limiting HTTP requests.  That transparent image is for styling purposes only.  If I can use CSS instead, I'll do it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem once, where using jQuery's .fadeOut() failed to animate opacity on the child elements of the element I was fading out in IE.
Back then, I got the issue fixed by adding css that told the child elements to specifically inherit the filter property of its parent, like:

## fadeElement * { filter: inherit; }